# Detect the order of seasonality of a daily time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with some daily time series (unequally spaced) problem and want to detect the order of seasonality (and/or the frequency of the data if necessary).
I know there is seasonality from the time series plot and ACF plot. The features of seasonality is obvious. My code looks like the following:

```
plot(mydates, mydata, type="l")
Acf(mydata)
```

I tried to fit the data using auto.arima, but It returns a non-seasonal fit.

```
auto.arima(mydata)
```

Series: mydata, ARIMA(1,0,1) with zero mean, Coefficients: ....

I also tried function nsdiffs, and it doesn't work either.

```
nsdiffs(mydata)
Error in nsdiffs(tslist[[1]]) : Non seasonal data
nsdiffs(ts(mydata, frequency=90))
0
```

I technically cannot use the ts function because I don't really know the frequency of my data (which is what I intend to find out). But I tested anyway, using some random guess of the frequency. It returns 0 every time.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to help you without data. But, I think [this blog](http://www.r-bloggers.com/detecting-seasonality/) should help you to detect seasonality.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1214/159